# removing backslash with tr

Tags: bash, macos, tr

So Im removing special characters from filenames and replacing with spaces. I have all working apart from files with single backslashes contained therein. 
Note these files are created in the Finder on OS X

```
old_name="testing\this\folder"
new_name=$(echo $old_name | tr '<>:\\#%|?*' ' ');
```

This results in new_name being "testing hisolder"
How can I just removed the backslashes and not the preceding character?

Comment: Depending on how you define _special characters_, you may be able to make use of something like `tr -d '[:punct:]'`

Comment: This is a great suggestion -- takes away the 'escape the escape' concept and just removes slashes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This results in new_name being "testing hisolder"

This string looks like the result of `echo -e "testing\this\folder"`, because *`\t` and `\f` are actually replaced with the tabulation and form feed control characters*.

Maybe you have an alias like `alias echo='echo -e'`, or maybe the implementation of `echo` in your version of the shell interprets backslash escapes:

> POSIX does not require support for any options, and says that the
>   behavior of ‘echo’ is implementation-defined if any STRING contains a
>   backslash or if the first argument is ‘-n’.  Portable programs can use
>   the ‘printf’ command if they need to omit trailing newlines or output
>   control characters or backslashes.

*(from the info page)*

So you should use `printf` instead of `echo` in new software. In particular, `echo $old_name` should be replaced with `printf %s "$old_name"`.

There is a good explanation in [this discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo), for instance.

**No need for `printf`**

As @mklement0 suggested, you can avoid the pipe by means of the [Bash here string](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html):

```
tr '<>:\\#%|?*' ' ' <<<"$old_name"
```

Answer (score 3):

[Ruslan's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40490970/45375) explains why your command may not be working for you and offers a robust, portable solution.

**tl;dr**:

- You probably ran your code with `sh` rather than `bash` (even though on macOS `sh` is Bash in disguise), or you had shell option `xpg_echo` explicitly turned on.
- Use `printf` instead of `echo` for portability.

---

In Bash, with the default options and using the `echo` builtin, your command should work as-is (except that you should double-quote `$old_name` for robustness), because `echo` by default does *not* expand escape sequences such as `\t` in its operands.

However, Bash's `echo` *can* be made to expand control-character escape sequences:

- explicitly, by executing `shopt -s xpg_echo`
- implicitly, if you run Bash as `sh` or with the `--posix` option (which, among other options and behavior changes, activates `xpg_echo`)

Thus, your symptom may have been caused by running your code from a script with shebang line `#!/bin/sh`, for instance.

However, if you're targeting `sh`, i.e., if you're writing a *portable* script, then `echo` should be avoided altogether for the very reason that its behavior differs across shells and platforms - see Ruslan's `printf` solution.

---

As an aside: perhaps a more robust approach to your `tr` command is a *whitelisting* approach: stating only the characters that are explicitly allowed in your result, and excluding other with the `-C` option:

```
old_name='testing\this\folder'
new_name=$(printf '%s' "$old_name" | tr -C '[:alnum:]_-' ' ')
```

That way, any characters that aren't either letters, numbers, `_`, or `-` are replaced with a space.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation also

Answer (score 1):

With Bash, you can use parameter expansion:

```
$ old_name="testing\this\folder"
$ new_name=${old_name//[<>:\\#%|?*]/ }
$ echo $new_name
testing this folder
```

For more, please refer to the Bash manual on [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Answer (score -1):

I think your test case is missing proper escaping for `\`, so you're not really testing the case of a backslash contained in a string.

This worked for me:

```
old_name='testing\\this\\folder'
new_name=$(echo $old_name | tr '<>:\\#%|?*' ' ');
echo $new_name
# testing this folder
```

Comment: In Bash (which is how the question is tagged), with default options, using its `echo` builtin, this preserves _both_ backslashes, and the resulting string will have _2_ spaces between the words. (Conversely, the OP's code should work as-is.) Aside from that, `$old_name` should be double-quoted. Your escaping would only work with option `xpg_echo` turned on (implicitly or explicitly), but the much better solution is to use `printf` or a here-string.